# Выборка в таблице по вхождению слов длинее 20ти символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, select, mysql

Здравствуйте. Суть вопроса следующая - есть таблицы, в ней поля "model" и "id". Поле "model" может хранить в себе несколько слов разной длины, слова разделены пробелом. Например "какое-то произвольное название модели" или "суперпупердлинноеназваниемодели с ошибкой". Необходимо выбрать записи в которых хотя бы одно слово в названии модели будет длиннее 22 символов. Т.е. первое название модели не попадает в результат выборки, а второе попадает. 
Пробовал типа такого:

```
SELECT id, model FROM `table1` WHERE model REGEXP "[А-Яа-яa-zA-Z]{22,}"
```

Но выборка работает не корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp:  `[А-яA-z]{22,}`

[image]

UPD: вроде всё [работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acf0a/2)

Comment: регулярное выражение отрабатывает не корректно в запросе

Comment: почему бы [А-яA-z] не заменить на \w ?

Comment: Потому как \w включает  в себя [A-z_]

Comment: @ua6xh не глобализируйте задачу. У автора черным по белому написано ". Поле "model" может хранить в себе несколько слов разной длины". Не нужно придумывать другие знаки.

Comment: @lampa 
>Не нужно придумывать другие знаки.

Какие другие знаки я придумал?

Comment: вот скриншот http://listick.ru/share/wD6SI  выборки запроса (SELECT id, menutitle
FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE menutitle REGEXP '[A-zА-я]{20,}') , хотя если вот здесь то этот же запрос отрабатывает корректно http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/766f0a/1   Почему так происходит не могу понять. Кодировка таблиц и БД - utf8_general_ci